# Django: to pass data JSON from view to javascript

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have my model

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)



class Event(models.Model):
....
calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, verbose_name=_('categorie'))
```

and my view:

```
event_list = []
events = Event.objects.all()

for event in events:
    event_list.append({
            'categorie': event.calendar
            })

return http.HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_list),
                             content_type='application/json')
```

I try to return event.categorie in a javascript file but It's not working
alert(event.categorie) display undefined....

if I print event_list, I have

```
{'categorie': <Calendar: thermique>}
```

The problem comes from  models.ForeignKey ?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to get a list of, is it just the calendar names?

Comment: it just the calendar names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dumps Calendar instance to json. You should get error `TypeError <Calendar: thermique> is not JSON serializable`.

You need convert Calendar instance to dict of simple types. For example add method `as_dict` to Calendar:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
        }
```

and use it in you code:

```
for event in events:
    event_list.append({
        'categorie': event.calendar.as_dict(),
    })
```

Comment: if you write `alert(event.categorie.name)` you see name of calendar

Comment: yes, I see the name with alert(event.categorie.name) thanks

Answer (score 0):

> it just the calendar names

Since all you need is the calendar names you can modify your query a little bit to use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) but the real problem is probably called by needing to resolve the queryset

```
events = Event.objects.values('calendar__name')
return http.JsonResponse(status=200, 
                         {'categories': json.dumps(list(events))})
```

Comment: http.HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_list) works fine if its not a model.ForeignKey in the model...

Comment: @Patrice - Thats because its not having to figure out what you want it to return, `json.dumps` isn't great at working with relational models since it needs further database queries to get the values